# does Netbeans Create "equals" method correctlly?

Tags: jpa, netbeans, hashcode

When creating an entity from Database, Netbeans creates **equals method**:

```
    public boolean equals(Object object){
       if(!(object instanceof Department)){
          return false;
       }
       Department other = (Department) object;
       return !(
                 (this.id == null && other.id != null) ||
                 (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))
               );
    }
```

And **return statement** according to:

~((A ∧ ~C) ∨  (~A ∧  ~B)) → (~A ∨ C) ∧  (A ∨ B) → (C ∨ B)

Equals to:

```
(other.id == null) || (this.id.equals(other.id))
```

**1.** Is this correct or should i change it to:

```
(this.id != null) && (this.id.equals(other.id))
```

**2.** Should i use a number like 10, instead of auto increment id in **hashCode method** ?

**3.** should a Natural Id or business id be immutable completely or can be changed. i mean, should i define a **setter method** for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE] Netbeans created the method correctly, as you can see it uses ! in the comparison, that is why he uses OR and !equals inside:

```
return !(
         (this.id == null && other.id != null) ||
         (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))
       );
```

So, following the implementation for Objects.equals (since 1.7) this would be preferable:

```
(this.id != null) && (this.id.equals(other.id))
```

And instead of this code for equals and hashCode, you could have:

```
import java.util.Objects;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) return true;
    if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
    Department department = (Department) object;
    return Objects.equals(id, department.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}
```

Here it is the implementation that Objects.hash calls in the end:

```
public static int hashCode(Object a[]) {
    if (a == null)
        return 0;

    int result = 1;

    for (Object element : a)
        result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());

    return result;
}
```

2. About the hashCode method, it is good to use the same fields as you use in the equals.
   Here, try to use fields that identify the entity as one, for example:

   - the field **name** it is unique, then use the name.
   - the field **name** and **number** are unique, then use both.
3. Once the object was created, you shouldn't have a setter for your Id field. You can have a constructor where you receive it instead to use in unit tests but not a setter. Immutable objects are a good approach to follow, but if you can't, at least the field that identifies the instance shouldn't change.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you, Brother! Did the netbeans create the method correctly? could you explain more about your **hashCode** method. It's totally different from what i saw around the internet and why is this static? Assume that, I have **Amenity** Entity in **Accommodation** project that has a persistent field called **name**. should i use it for hashCode? and what about persistent field **name** in **Service** Entity? i mean, can i use **@NaturalId** for them and use them for hashCode?

Comment: Hi @Arash, first: Yes, netbeans created the method correctly. I updated my answer explaining why. My hashcode method it is not static, the method that Objects.hash() calls inside is, that is java.util.Arrays.hashCode. About fields used in the HashCode and Equals, try to use fields that identify your entity as unique, it the name it is unique, then the name, if the name + another field it is unique, use both, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, Brother. Assume The **name** field is unique but may rarely change.Is this OK to use it as **NaturalId** in the hashCode? and why shouldn't use something like this: **return (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);**? and what is **31**? why not 30 or another number? how do you get to this computational statement : **31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());**?

Comment: And why did you use **if (this == object) return true;**  we are comparing these two with **equals** method right?

Comment: Hi @Arash, this code and magic number 31 are from Java library, and it is a prime number, that is why it is used. About the "if (this == object) return true; " it is for comparing the reference in memory, for example: if you have two variables pointing to the same object in memory it returns true and don't need to go deep and compare id, name or the class.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brother. If i understood correctly, **==** is reference comparison and **equals** is content comparison, right? And is it OK for **NaturalId** in **hashCode()** to change rarely?

Comment: Welcome @Arash, yes for objects, == compares the reference and equals the content. And it is ok to use NaturalId in the hashCode.